How can I handle or correct shapefile coordinates that exceed valid latitude and longitude ranges? How do softwares like QGIS project invalid ones?
I am working on making a shapefile data parser and there are some shapefiles that when I upload to QGIS and GEE work perfectly fine but my parser says its invalid because the latitude and longitude are big values like 1000 and more instead of the valid range -180 to 180 and -90 to 90. How do I project/map these big numbers to the valid range without losing the information these coordianates intend to contain?
I tried to take a mod but that doesn't work.

Not all shapefiles are in lat, lon (EPSG:4326 or WGS84) so there are no limits on the size of coordinates. You will need to look at the contents of the .prj file to work out how to reproject the coordinates to EPSG:4326.
But I would really discourage you from going to the lengths of writing your own shapefile parser. I was involved in writing one back in the 1990s and we are still fixing obscure corner case bugs now. There are well tested and (mostly) working open source Shapefile readers and writers in most languages that you should consider using. If you are on some really weird architecture that can't use existing code then use a more modern format rather than the obsolete Shapefile.
